# Meaning of "die words of Deuteronomy"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The following passage is from the book *The Demonologist: The Extraordinary Career of Ed and Lorraine Warren*:

> Sharon Beckford had reacted on a
> more personal level. Why was this
> violence, destruction, vulgarity, and hate
> permitted to go on? For their whole life,
> they’d worked to build a good home and
> raise a proper family. They and their children attended church every Sunday.
> With tears of anger, Sharon Beckford asked forceful questions to which there
> were no ready answers: “If this is the
> devil at work, then where is God? Is it
> just for our whole home to be destroyed
> because our daughter used a Ouija board?”

> Father Daniel sympathized with
> Sharon Beckford. Her questions
> required a reply, however, and the priest
> was forced to answer her through **die
> words** in Chapter 18 of Deuteronomy:
> “Let there not be found among you
> anyone who immolates his son or
> daughter in the fire, nor a fortune-teller,
> soothsayer, charmer, diviner, or caster
> of spells, nor one who consults ghosts and spirits or seeks oracles from the
> dead Anyone who does such things is an
> abomination to the Lord.”

English is not my first language and I don't understand the meaning of that. I have looked up every meaning of the relevant words, but I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146188/discussion-on-question-by-majid-mashmool-meaning-of-die-words-of-deuteronomy); please do not continue the discussion here.